# If $P[|X| < \infty] = 1$ and $\epsilon > 0$, there exists a bounded RV $Y$ with $P[X \neq Y] < \epsilon$

Tags: probability-theory

> If $X$ is a random variable satisfying $P[|X| \lt \infty]=1$, then show that for any $\epsilon >0$, there exists a bounded random variable $Y$ such that $P[X \neq Y] \lt \epsilon$.

Note: A random variable $Y$ is bounded if for all $\omega$, $|Y(\omega)| \le K$ for some $K$ independent of $\omega$.

I could not understand this question and solve it.

Thanks and regards.

Comment: **Hint**: Truncate.

Comment: The question is asking you to find a random variable $Y$ that is (a) bounded, as you describe, and (b) equal to $X$ on the whole space excepting a set of arbitrary small measure. The condition on $X$ is that it is almost surely finite. So, think about what that says about the measure of the set on which $X$ takes "large" values, i.e., $|X| > B$ for some large $B$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am just making cardinal's point precise. Since $P(|X|<\infty)=1$, $P(\bigcap_n\{|X|>n\})=0$, and hence $\lim_{n\to \infty}P(|X|>n)=0$.

Now, let $Y_n=X\cdot 1_{\{|X|\le n\}}$. Then $Y_n$ are all bounded and $\{X\neq Y_n\}=\{|X|>n\}$.

Hence , for given $\epsilon>0$, there exists $Y_n$ such that $P(X\neq Y_n)<\epsilon$.

Comment: I don't understand that Why  P(⋂n{|X|>n})=0 ?
Could you explain precisely? Thanks.

Comment: For an $\omega$, $|X(\omega)|=\infty$ iff $|X(\omega)|>n$ for all $n$, right?

Comment: Could you prove this or introduce related concept? 
Maybe I will get this sense accurately.

Comment: That is the way $\infty$ is defined, right?

Comment: Why is the way ∞ defined ?

Comment: @Ashok what does $1_{\{ |X| \le n}\}$ mean ?

Comment: It means the indicator $I(|X|\le n)$